# Using Accelerometer and Calibration with Swift 3 and Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I originally had written the code for Swift 2, however, when I upgraded to Swift 3 and Xcode 8, some of the code broke. How do I use the accelerometer and have calibration in Xcode 8 with Swift 3?

I realize the issue is with CGVectorMake - it says it's unavailable in Swift. What to replace it with?

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import CoreMotion

class GameScene: SKScene {
    let Manager = CMMotionManager()
    var bg = SKSpriteNode()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        Manager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
        Manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1
        Manager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main){
                (data, error) in

            self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake (CGFloat((data?.acceleration.x)! * 10), CGFloat((data?.acceleration.y)! * 10))
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the init syntax for `CGVector`:

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: CGFloat((data?.acceleration.x)! * 10), dy: CGFloat((data?.acceleration.y)! * 10))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It fixed my problem.